# Expected content of a dynamic vector

Tags: c++, dynamic, vector

I have to store integer values which are mapped to other integers. One way to do it is use a std::map m. But then to retrieve the value using m[int] or m.find(int), will be an order of logN (N is number of elements) time. In my case N is pretty large (upto 2^30). I thought using a std::vector will be faster for access as each key now maps to index of a vector element, which can be accessed in O(1) time. The key is encountered in random order and they may not be contiguous. For e.g., if the vector has size 10, then not all 10 elements are valid and there could only be 6 valid elements and rest I need to fill with -1. I wrote a small program and I'm surprised to find output below:

```
int main () {
   std::vector<int> v;
   v.assign(6, -1); 
   v[3] = 10; 
   v[10] = 100;
   cout << v.size() << v.capacity() << endl ;
   cout << v[3] << v[10] << endl; 
}
```

The output seen is size = 6, capacity = 6, V[3] = 10, v[10] = 100. I do not understand how size and capacity are 6, but v[10] has a valid value or I did not encounter a seg. fault. Can someone explain this? My understanding is push_back function dynamically resizes the vector when vector.size > vector.capacity, does operator [] also do this? To be safe, I re-wrote the above code as :

```
int main () {
   std::vector<int> v;
   v.assign(6, -1);
   int key = getKey(); 
   if (key < v.size()) 
      v[key] = <correct value>;
   else {
      v.resize(key, -1); // I want to assign -1 to invalid elements
      v[key-1] =  <correct value>;
   }
}
```

It seems to be working fine, but will it be better to compare key with v.capacity() and then resize the vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
std::vector<int> v;
v.assign(6, -1); 
v[3] = 10; 
v[10] = 100;  // Unlucky with this statement
```

The size of the vector is just **6**. And the accessing index is from **0 to 5**. Your first snippet has undefined behavior that you got unlucky that it didn't break when accessing an index **10**. If there is a notion a key association with a value, then associative containers like `std::map` or `std::multimap` would be better than a sequence container like `std::vector`.

Comment: It looks like undefined behavior and for some reason the seg. fault did not happen in the test program. when I wrote a longer program on different platform, I saw similar output, but program crashed at end of execution.

Answer (score 3):

> My understanding is push_back function dynamically resizes the vector
>   when vector.size > vector.capacity, does operator [] also do this?

No, it does not. If you access past the end of your vector using `operator[]`, the behaviour of your code is undefined. You have to explicitly resize the vector to make sure it is large enough for any access through `operator[]`.

`std::vector::at()` is similar to `operator[]` but does perform error checking and may therefore be useful in spotting out-of-bounds access (but there's going to be a performance cost of carrying out those extra checks).

If you expect your data structure to be relatively sparse, it may be worth considering `std::unordered_map` for the job.

In any case, I hope you realize that `2^30` ints will take a fair amount of RAM (4GB if `int` is 32 bits wide). Even if your hardware/OS will allow you to have an array that big, you may have to pre-allocate it rather than grow it through repeated reallocations.

Comment: -support for boost is not available in all platforms we work on, so cannot use unordered_map. +1 for mentioning this.

Comment: @srikrish: there is also `std::tr1::unordered_map`. But if you cannot have boost I am not sure if you will have TR1.